# Delphi: How to draw some text in requested width and number of lines, with ending ellipsis?

Tags: delphi, text, drawing, ellipsis, drawtext

I need to draw some text in a table cell with fixed width (in pixels) and fixed number of text lines. If the text is clipped by cell rectangle, it must end with ellipsis. The problem is I can't calculate the text rectangle correctly (or the TextRect/DrawText procedure isn't working correctly, I'm not sure).

I tried to use this method of calculating text rectangle:

```
var
  TextRect: TRect;
  tm: TEXTMETRIC;
...
GetTextMetrics(Canvas.Handle, tm);
TextLineHeight := tm.tmHeight + tm.tmExternalLeading;

TextRect.Bottom := TextRect.Top + TextLineHeight * NumberOfLines;
Canvas.TextRect(TextRect, 'some long long long text',
  [tfTop, tfLeft, tfEndEllipsis, tfWordBreak]);
```

The clipping rectangle has been calculated correctly, but the ellipsis isn't appearing.

Ellipsis appearing when I decrease the height of clipping rectangle by 1 pixel:

```
TextRect.Bottom := TextRect.Top + TextLineHeight * NumberOfLines - 1;
```

But some pixels of the bottom line of my text are clipped then.

How to do it correctly?

Comment: You use both `TargetCanvas` and `Canvas`. Is that intentional?

Comment: oops, it is the same Canvas, just mistyped when writing question.

Comment: Putting ellipsis only when the last line does not fit is really strange.. One ugly workaround could be to first draw it like that but by also specifying `tfModifyString`, then incrementing 'TextRect.Bottom' and drawing the modified (with ellipsis at the end) text just as is.

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz: can you move this comment into answers? I'll check it as accepted. You solution works fine! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the api puts the end-ellipsis only when the last line does not fit in the specified rectangle, one workaround could be to specify `tfModifyString`in formatting options in a first call to 'TextRect' with a rectangle with reduced height, then call 'TextRect' again with a proper sized rectangle and the modified text:

```
var
  Text: string;
...

  Text := 'some long long long text';
  SetLength(Text, Length(Text) + 4); // as per DrawTextEx documentation

  Dec(TextRect.Bottom);
  Canvas.TextRect(TextRect, Text,
      [tfTop, tfLeft, tfEndEllipsis, tfWordBreak, tfModifyString]);

  Inc(TextRect.Bottom);
  Canvas.TextRect(TextRect, Text, [tfTop, tfLeft, tfWordBreak]);
```

I'd be keeping an eye though, in case a future version of the OS decides to clip the last line entirely if it doesn't entirely fit in the rectangle.. :)

Comment: I have a small remark: it is better to draw the text with tfModifyString somewhere behind the visible area on Canvas, because writing the same text twice on the same place affects font antialiasing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try calculating the needed rectangle via `Canvas.TextRect(..., [tfCalcRect, ...])`.

Comment: But I don't know which part of text should I trim to draw it within my limited NumberOfLines

Comment: @Andrew: Sorry, no more ideas. But try googling for `DT_END_ELLIPSIS DT_WORDBREAK` (the API equivalents for tfEndEllipsis and tfWordBreak). You'll find lots of problems and maybe some solutions. :-)